# Redux ToolKit and React Native. Error: could not find react-redux context value;

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I was following all the [Quick Start](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/quick-start) tutorial for Redux Toolkit, but it's throws me the following error:

**Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the
component is wrapped in a Provider**

I don't know why, the Provider wrappe my App.js component and I dont use any Redux Hook inside the App component

This is my App component:

```
import React from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import CustomDrawer from "./Components/CustomDrawer.jsx";
import Authentication from "./Pages/Authentication.jsx";
import Home from "./Pages/Home.jsx";
import { store } from "./Redux/Store.js";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";



const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();


export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Drawer.Navigator 
        screenOptions={{ 
          headerStyle: { 
            elevation: 0, 
            shadowOpacity: 0 
          }, 
          headerTransparent: true,
          headerTitle: '' 
        }} 
        drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawer  {...props} />}>

          <Drawer.Screen 
          name="Home" 
          component={Home} 
          />
          <Drawer.Screen 
          name="Register" 
          component={Authentication} 
          />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

I have also seen the React Navigator documentation and it does not say anything about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I solved the bug.... All I did was reposition my Drawe.Screen components, refresh the application and then put them back as they were. I don't know what happened but somehow it fixed it.